# Strange behaviour for what should be constant boolean evaluation

Tags: c#

I was playing around with the wonderful [SharpLab.io](https://sharplab.io/) trying to better my understanding of c# lowering when I came across some very strange behaviour.

I was observing the lowering of the following expression

```
public class C {

    bool a;

    public void M() 
    {
       a = a && false;
    } 
}
```

Seems to be being lowered to

```
public class C
{
    private bool a;

    public void M()
    {
        a = !a && false;
    }
}
```

And `a = !a && false;` is lowered to `a = a && false;`

My questions are

- Whats going here, why is it lowering the code from `a && false` to `!a && false`
- Why is it also doing the oposite (`!a && false` to `a && false`)
- Why can it not tell this expression will always evaluate to simply `false` (I would understand for ref types that can override the `bool` cast but this is litterally the inbuilt `bool` type)

(`a = false && a`, `a = false && !a` are both correctly lowered to `a = false`)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "lowered", but can you explain what makes you think that this is happening?  In other words, what is happening that makes you think that this change is taking place?

Comment: @RBarryYoung [here is a blog post](https://mattwarren.org/2017/05/25/Lowering-in-the-C-Compiler/) explaining what lowering is, its an optimisation / simplification step before translation to bytecode. I have no idea at all why this is happening, It's totally got me stumped. Maybe I just don't understand how boolean logic works

Comment: No, I mean, what evidence do you have that this is happening?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, sorry. I'm using a web tool which shows the output of lowered c# code using I belive a Roslyn compiler. https://sharplab.io/

Comment: if the behavior of the code does not reflect this change, then I would question whether the tool is correct.  And this is "lowering" because there's no high-level feature being turned into a low-level feature that I can see.  It would be an invalid compiler transformation if it were actually doing it, but I have doubts that it is,

Comment: About "Why can it not tell this expression will always evaluate to simply false", it's probably related to short circuit logic, `false && a` and `true || a` can be short-circuited without reading `a` at all, but not `a && false` and `a || true`, sure if it's simple boolean variable there's no side effect, but if it's a property there might be. The compiler dev probably picks the more general solution instead of optimizing the special case of a boolean variable.

Comment: Short-circuit boolean evaluation is turned on by default, I believe.

Comment: @RBarryYoung sharplab.io isn't just a tool, it shows the intermediate and final output of the Roslyn and JIT compilers. It's used by everyone, including the C# team members.

Answer (score 0):

since the result of M is always going to be that a == false it really doesnt matter if you see `a` or `!a`. Ilspy says the same when i look at the output of vs2022

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [System.Runtime]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private bool a

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 20 (0x14)
        .maxstack 8

        // {
        IL_0000: nop
        // a = !a && false;
        IL_0001: ldarg.0
        IL_0002: ldarg.0
        IL_0003: ldfld bool C::a
        IL_0008: brfalse.s IL_000d

        IL_000a: ldc.i4.0
        IL_000b: br.s IL_000e

        IL_000d: ldc.i4.0

        IL_000e: stfld bool C::a
        // }
        IL_0013: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2065
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        // {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        // (no C# code)
        IL_0001: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Object::.ctor()
        // }
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```